# Why does 11+1=3?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I don't get it. A friend asked ne this but I don't know what to say. I tried to see if it had to deal with integers or something, but I got nothing.

Comment: is it more of a joke than a riddle? 1+1+1 is 3, so "confusing" 11 with "two ones" would give you three.

Comment: True for very large values of 3, or small values of 11 :D

Comment: 11+1 = 12 = 1+2 = 3... Few people who beleives in astrology and numbers are sometimes use this trick to find their lucky number..!! Strange to listen, but true at some region..!

Comment: Have you considered that your friend might not know how to add?

Comment: I might have said it equals 4 in binary.

Comment: Two ones plus one is three?

Comment: May be addition using Roman Numbers   II + I = III

Comment: @H.Modh That's called the `Digital-sum` in math.

Answer (score 13):

A rather simplistic solution

> Your friend considers $1$ as a tally mark instead of a digit,
>  Hence $$||+|=|||=3$$

Comment: Equally valid for roman numerals!

Answer (score 6):

> 11 people, plus one more, equals 3 barbershop quartets!